# chez scheme - load-shared-object based on platform

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

The [OpenGL library for Chez Scheme](https://github.com/dharmatech/chez-gl) (currently only setup for Linux) loads the GLUT library as follows:

```
(define no-op (load-shared-object "libglut.so.3"))
```

Here's a [link](https://github.com/dharmatech/chez-gl/blob/7a75fc93496d25a348657f06126790655651bdb1/glut.sls#L195) to that code.

Of course, we'd like the library to load `libglut.so.3` on Linux but `GLUT.framework/GLUT` on macOS.

Here's an example of how Ypsilon Scheme loads libraries based on the platform:

```
(define libGLUT
  (cond
    (on-darwin  (load-shared-object "GLUT.framework/GLUT"))
    (on-windows (load-shared-object "glut32.dll"))
    (on-linux   (load-shared-object "libglut.so.3"))
    (on-freebsd (load-shared-object "libglut.so"))
    (on-openbsd (begin
             (load-shared-object "libXmu.so.10.0")
             (load-shared-object "libGLU.so.7.0")
             (load-shared-object "libglut.so.3.7")))
    (else
     (assertion-violation
      #f
          "can not locate GLUT library, unknown operating system"))))
```

What's a good way to check the platform on Chez Scheme so that we can do something similar in our bindings for foreign libraries?

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/blob/master/examples/socket.ss:

```
(case (machine-type)
  [(i3le ti3le) (load-shared-object "libc.so.6")]
  [(i3osx ti3osx a6osx ta6osx) (load-shared-object "libc.dylib")]
  [else (load-shared-object "libc.so")])
```

Using `meta-cond` instead will give you slightly more efficient run-time behavior, since it will be resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

How about `(machine-type)` ?

```
~ % uname -m -p -r -s
Darwin 15.6.0 x86_64 i386
~ % chez
Chez Scheme Version 9.4.1
Copyright 1984-2016 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (machine-type)
ta6osx
```